# Optimizing a multi join oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have the below sql Oracle query that is functional however a bit slow on a large amount of data. I have looked into the execution plan and all the indexes are used and couldn't find a way to speed the query more:

```
 select n.ID_DOC as RECORDKEY,
        n.ID_TYPE_DOC as ID_TYPE_DOC,
        r.MN_TYPE_DOC as MN_TYPE_DOC,
        p.NUM_PLI as NUM_PLI,
        p.ID_ORIG as ID_ORIG 
        from DOCUMENT n 
        inner join CSFOLDITEM i on i.ITEMSUPPID = n.ID_DOC 
        inner join REF_TYPE_DOCUMENT r on r.ID_TYPE_DOC = n.ID_TYPE_DOC 
        inner join PLI p on P.ID_PLI = i.FOLDSUPPID 
        where n.ID_DOC in () ;
```

I tried another approach as the one below, however the cost was same and the response time was practically similar:

```
select t1.ID_DOC,t1.ID_TYPE_DOC,t2.MN_TYPE_DOC,t3.NUM_PLI,t3.ID_ORIG from
            (select ID_DOC,ID_TYPE_DOC 
            from DOCUMENT where ID_DOC in ()) t1
           inner join
           (select ID_TYPE_DOC,MN_TYPE_DOC 
            from REF_TYPE_DOCUMENT ) t2
           ON (t1.ID_TYPE_DOC = t2.ID_TYPE_DOC)
          inner join
           (select c.ITEMSUPPID as ITEMSUPPID,p.NUM_PLI as NUM_PLI,p.ID_ORIG as ID_ORIG
            from PLI p inner join CSFOLDITEM c
            on p.ID_PLI = c.FOLDSUPPID) t3
           ON (t3.ITEMSUPPID = t1.ID_DOC) ;
```

Any suggestions on what I can possibly do to get a faster response time?

The execution plan for the 1st query for a single record in the IN clause:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show the execution plan with the cardinality estimation ? I don't see any cardinality estimation in your picture. How much time does the query takes ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I added the plan output table, I am not sure if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: @mikeb, thanks, that it is what I was looking for. However, how much time does it take the query ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez for 400 records in the IN clause it can take up to 12 seconds

Comment: try to run this in sqlplus `set autotrace traceonly` and then run the query with the in values . post the output

Answer (score 1):

The plan looks ok, from my point of view, but you can stress it using more indexes, avoiding in this case the access to the table.

Let me explain what I just said. Your plan shows `TABLE ACCESS BY ROWID` after an access to an index ( `INDEX UNIQUE SCAN` , `INDEX RANGE SCAN` ). It means that Oracle is using the index to find which row contains the data, but it needs to access the table because the select contains a field or fields which are not present in the index.

One approach to solve this would be to create new indexes, therefore Oracle will only need to access them to recover the data. For example

```
create index idx_document on document ( id_doc , id_type_doc ) ;

create index idx_ref_type_document on ref_type_document ( id_type_doc , mn_type_doc );

create index idx_pli on pli ( id_pli , id_orig, num_pli ) ;
```

**However, keep in mind that creating more indexes will improve the performance of the query, but it will decrease the performance of DML operations against the aforementioned tables. You need to evaluate whether is worth it or not.**

Another issue could be the estimation cardinality, try to collect statistics for all the tables involved in the query using `cascade => true` that you collect also for all indexes.